# How to fail a bamboo script if an element inside the script fails

Tags: bamboo

We use a script step in Bamboo to build our application, using the dotnet build powershell command.

However, if the dotnet build fails to compile, the step still reports success, I'm guessing this is because although the build fails, the script still executed.  Is there a way to have the script step fail, if the build inside the script fails?

As an alternative, I'm looking at replacing the script with MSBuild / MSTestRunner steps, got the build working but struggling on the test runner (no selectable executables), our bamboo instance is locked down so I need a third party to add executables etc, which isn't a fast process, so having the script step report failures properly is preferable.

Comment: Start your script with `set -e`.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo script tasks depend on the exit status code returned by the script execution.

In your case, the script itself is returning success, even though the compile job failed. This is likely because there are other steps after the build that are returning 0. The script itself will only return the last error value of the last action in the script unless you specifically change this.

I would just check the $LASTEXITCODE built in variable after compilation and maybe exit the script right after fail.

```
  dotnet build

  if($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) {
      exit 1
  }
```

Or save it to a variable and check it after the other tasks complete if you need those to run even if the build fails.